# Scala Type Failure in 2.7: is there a workaround?

Tags: generics, scala, scala-2.8, type-inference

I have a problem using a parameterized class as the key-type of a `Map`. First create the parameterized class:

```
scala> sealed abstract class Foo[T]{  def t: T }
defined class Foo
```

Now create some imaginary collection of these across unknown parameters:

```
scala> var l: List[Foo[_]] = Nil
l: List[Foo[_]] = List()
```

Now create a Map to store these in:

```
scala> var mm: Map[Foo[_], Any] = Map.empty
mm: Map[Foo[_],Any] = Map()
```

Now attempt to populate the Map

```
scala> l.foreach { foo: Foo[_] =>
     | mm += (foo -> "BAR")
     | }
```

Gives me the following compiler error:

> ```
> <console>:9: error: type mismatch;  
> found   : foo.type (with underlying type Foo[_])  
> required: Foo[_$1] where type _$1  
>        mm += (foo -> "BAR")  
>               ^
> ```

This compiles just fine in 2.8. Is there any workaround to get this to work in 2.7?

**EDIT** - this also worked for me:

```
var mm: Map[AnyRef, Any] = Map.empty //note not Foo[_]

scala> l.foreach { foo: Foo[_] =>
     | mm += ( (foo: AnyRef) -> "BAR") //still have to tell compiler foo is an AnyRef
     | }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works well for me (even in Scala 2.7):

```
scala> l.foreach { foo: Foo[_] =>
     | mm += (foo.asInstanceOf[Foo[_]] -> "BAR")
     | }
```

Weird, but this really seems to be a bug in 2.7 which has been fixed in 2.8.